# InfoBox closebox margins acting strange

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've added closebox pic to one global infobox, and position of closeboxes varies from marker to marker. Content of infobox is tweet's embed code. Here are print screens made on same map with different markers.

pic1 http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2i/Y5/EHd2zmx/daleko.jpg

pic2 http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1t/74/3B7tQxCv/blizu.jpg

And here is my options code (it is the only place I set up margins and closebox):

```
    var infobox1 = new InfoBox({
        //content: boxText,
        disableAutoPan: true,
        isHidden:false,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-10, -10),
        closeBoxMargin: "-10px -20px 2px 2px",
        closeBoxURL: "./images/close50.png",
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: true,
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        });
```

And this is embed code, content of infobox:

```
var str2 = '<div class="twcont" style="" ><blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>'+text+'</p>&mdash; '+name+' (@'+screen_name+') ';
str2 += '<a href="'+link+'">'+datum+'</a></blockquote></div>';
//str2 += '<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></' + 'script><div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add custom style to infobox div. Somehow its width was set 600px automatically. Add this to infobox options `boxStyle: {  width: "auto" },`